# Django: Grouping of records

Tags: python, django

Apologies if the title of question is not correct. Please someone correct it if the detail here gives you idea what I am asking for. I am not English speaker so may make a mistake in wording the title.

I have this model:

```
class ClinicDoctor(models.Model):
    doctor = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='doctorsF') # single quotes (') because User table is defined down the code.
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic, related_name='clinicsF')
```

I am trying to fetch all doctor records and their clinics. Some doctors may have multiple clinics. In my template I loop over the below query set:

```
doctorsQuerySet = ClinicDoctor.objects.filter(doctor__groups__name='Doctor')
```

This returns records BUT I wanted to show records in a table like this:

DoctorHeader-------------ClinicsHeader
Doctor 1 ----------------Clinic 1, Clinic 2.
Doctor 2 ---------------- Clinic 3
Doctor 3 ---------------- Clinic 4, Clinic 5, clinic 7

The idea is that I want to show every Doctor only once and then put all his related clinics in that single row of that Doctor.

Right now I am looping over the query set in the template but that is going to show same doctor record multiple times(as many as associated clinics).

Is there any way in which I can modify that Query above to achieve the grouping or I will have to handle it in the template to see when Doctor_id changed from previous loop-run and concatenate the clinics and then put them in `<td>` tag?

I tried to search on SO but didn't find relevant questions to my situation. May be my wording while searching was not same as what I am looking for. So apologies if it has been already solved someone. You can share the link.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the data in the template you could use the following (note that the following code is not actually tested, but will hopefully get you in the right direction):

views.py

```
...
# Pass whatever model is the foreign key for "doctor" in the ClinicDoctor model
context = {"doctors": User.objects.all()}
...
```

template.html

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Doctor Header</th>
      <th>Clinics Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for doctor in doctors %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ doctor }}</td>
        <td>
          {% for clinicdoctor in doctor.clinicdoctor_set.all %}
            clinicdoctor.clinic{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

First pass in your doctors queryset to the template and then loop over them. The `clinicdoctor_set.all` will retrieve all ClinicDoctor entries for that doctor (the `_set.all` lets you retrieve all entries in a foreign key relationship in reverse). You can then reference the associated clinic foreign key normally.

The `{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}` will add a comma between each clinic entry, except for the last one of the loop.

You can read more on this under the [Related objects reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/) and the [Template reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#accessing-method-calls).